# how to implement autofac dependency injection with parameter in constructor or with any condition?

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, autofac, ioc-container

`Before using any dependency injection` I'm using simple `interface` to make a `loosely coupled code` like below -

**Program.cs**

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Customer obj = new Customer(new OracleData());
            obj.Add();
        }
    }
```

**Customer.cs**

```
 public class Customer
    {
        private Idata iobj;
        public Customer(Idata newiobj)
        {
            iobj = newiobj;
        }
        public void Add()
        {
            iobj.AddData();
        }
    }
```

**OracleData.cs**

```
 public class OracleData : Idata
    {
        public void AddData()
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
```

**SQLData.cs**

```
public class SQLData : Idata
{
    public void AddData()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

**Idata.cs**

```
 public interface Idata
    {
        void AddData();
    }
```

Now I tried this using `Autofac` DI library - 
I wonder it always its last injected class object , how to set resolve object using constructor or with any condition?

code using Autofac DI -

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
            builder.RegisterType<Customer>();
            builder.RegisterType<OracleData>().As<Idata>();
            builder.RegisterType<SQLData>().As<Idata>();
            var container = builder.Build();
            using (var scope = container.BeginLifetimeScope())
            {
                var app = scope.Resolve<Idata>();
                app.AddData();
            }

            //commented
            //Customer obj = new Customer(new OracleData());
            //obj.Add();
        }
```

Comment: You could use [names](http://docs.autofac.org/en/latest/advanced/keyed-services.html), i.e. `builder.Register<OracleData>().Named<Idata>("oracleData");` and `scope.ResolveNamed<Idata>("oracleData");`.

Comment: oh i see but how can we use it inside constructor or using any condition ?

Comment: As in the linked article, `public DataHandler([WithKey("oracleData")] Idata data) { ... }`

Comment: "Before using any dependency injection I'm using simple interface to make a loosely coupled code like below". Your example clearly shows dependency injection, so you were using dependency injection before, just not a IoC container, which is an optional tool when applying DI.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to define which implementation you will use at the entry point you can do something like this:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
        builder.RegisterType<Customer>();

        if(args[0] == "oracle")
            builder.RegisterType<OracleData>().As<Idata>();
        else
            builder.RegisterType<SQLData>().As<Idata>();

        var container = builder.Build();

        using (var scope = container.BeginLifetimeScope())
        {
            var app = scope.Resolve<Idata>();
            app.AddData();
        }

        //commented
        //Customer obj = new Customer(new OracleData());
        //obj.Add();
    }
```

Comment: but i suppose we have to register all the classes right irrespective of condition , we need to resolve it using condition or in constructor ?

Comment: you can directly do IData app = scope.Resolve<OracleData>(); if you need to decide later on.